# Add data into <option> tag in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to add data come from an angular file with the option.

This is the script file

```
 $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
            $scope.List1Details= data.List1Details;
             $scope.HeaderName= data.HeaderName;
        });
```

In View

```
 <select class="selection_light select_full_width" id="selectedTag1ID{{$index}}" ng-change="ChangeConfirmBtn($index)" ng-model="PendingEmployee.SelectedTag1ID" ng-options="Tag1.Id as Tag1.Name for Tag1 in List1Details">
 <option value="" selected>Choose {{HeaderName}}  </option>
 </select>
```

But it is displays as

> Choose {{HeaderName}}

Its shows like this when I render it in **IE**. It works fine on Chrome and Firefox

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: it seems ok, if you can provide a plunker for that we can help you better...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you concat your array with the first option, I know angular doesnt like the  option tag.